# Do new c++ warnings improve reliability?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings, compiler-warnings

So, I've been working in C++ after working in C# for a long time and I notice that there are all these warnings now.

While some warnings appears to be good recommendations to make the code more reliable, it seems like many of them don't. And a number of them seem completely wrong.

Here's an example of one that doesn't seem worthwhile to me:

```
static TCHAR szGeneral[] = _T("General");
static TCHAR szSqlOdbcDriver[] = _T("SqlOdbcDriver");

WriteProfileString(szGeneral, szSqlOdbcDriver, CSqlServerDatabase::m_sOdbcDriver.GetString());
```

> Warning C26485 Expression 'szGeneral': No array to pointer decay (bounds.3).
>
> Warning C26485 Expression 'szSqlOdbcDriver': No array to pointer decay (bounds.3).

My question is: does this make my code better?

I submit that I've had to turn off warnings because my project has almost 800 of them. (The code was considered perfectly valid when it was written ten years ago.) And so I will miss all the good recommendations. And the result of that would be that my code is worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this warning comes from Core Guidelines checker recently added to Visual Studio. Warnings from this checker will only make sense when you are writing new code from scratch and ready to follow Core Guidelines. Otherwise, turn off the checker.

The checker is a part of static code analyzer, and you should probably not include the analyzer in your compilation.

In your project properties, you have `/analyze` in `C/C++-->Command Line`. You should get rid of this flag (I do not know how to do it for your version of Visual Studio).

Do not turn off all warnings.

Comment: I'm going to work on this C++ project and then I'm back to C#, so there's no way I'm going to spend too much time figuring what each warning means and then deciding if I should disable it. If there's an easy way to disable these extreme warnings, then I'd be all for that.

Comment: I have added instructions to disable the analyzer.

Comment: Well, changing the settings that way would be an interesting approach, given that my project has a few hundred C++ files.

Comment: Edited the text. You just need to somehow get rid of `/analyze` flag.

Comment: Looks like I have the `/analyze-` flag. Guessing the hyphen at the end turns it off.

Comment: Yes,` /analyze-` is meant to turn off the static analyzer. Based on documentation, I thought Core Guidelines checker is a part of it. Do you have the flag in the same project configuration (e.g. Debug) that you are compiling? If so, I have no further ideas how to turn off Core Guidelines checker.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be an Intellisense sort of issue.

Answer (score 2):

IMO it is situation dependent.
For example, the compiler is giving warning because as soon as you are passing the char[] to the function you are losing the sizeof() information. However, that might not even matter as the strings are null terminated. But consider the case where somehow the nullptr is gone. Then how would you compute the length of it in the function?

To assist the compiler in such cases, I would recommend to explicitly tell compiler that you know what you are doing. This also makes intent visible.
consider -

```
long b = 50;
int a = b;
```

will generate a compiler warning, but depending upon the usage it might be safe.
but you are leaving team members with a guess (is it intended or error?).
Where

```
long b = 50;
int a = static_cast<int>(b);
```

makes clear that it is intended.

Comment: I am assuming WriteProfileString() is taking TCHAR*
In that case yes.
WriteProfileString(reinterpret_cast<TCHAR*>(szGeneral, ...
Would make it more visible IMO